# Using constant to call a function with that name in PHP

Tags: php

I have the following code:

```
$this->load->library('dummyLib');
$this->dummyLib->dummyLibFunction();
```

(I am using a PHP-Framework that works like that)

Now I want to be able to change the different libraries depending on a constant that I have defined priviously:

```
defined('LIB') OR define('LIB', 'dummy');
```

Which I can use like `$myLibrary = LIB`

As I have to load that library in different locations I want my code to automatically adjust to that constant. I know that function calls are possible with variables like this:

```
$myFunctionNameInThisVariable = 'test';
$this->$myFunctionNameInThisVariable();
```

This will call `$this->test()`

Can I do the same with constants? Or do I always have to use an additional variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question, let's compare function calls:

a normal function call is:

```
$this->functionName();
```

a function call with defined constant is

```
$this->CONSTANT_NAME();
```

As in php functions' names are **case insensitive**, php cannot understand what you want to do - call a function `CONSTANT_NAME` or replace constant `CONSTANT_NAME` with is real value. So, there's only one option here - find a function by **provided name** (`CONSTANT_NAME`) and execute it.

So, the answer is: **yes**, you should use a variable in this case.

Also, there's another option with using `call_user_func_` methods:

```
function callMe()
{
    echo '123';
}
define ('CALL_ME', 'callMe');
call_user_func(CALL_ME);
// yep, this works: https://3v4l.org/tbRrr
```

Comment: Well too bad. I hoped there was some syntax like `$this->{CONSTANT}()` or something, but well, thanks anyways